# How to create a templates directory in PyCharm Community Edition?

Tags: django, django-templates, pycharm

I want to create a directory of templates of Django in community edition of PyCharm. So I run this command:

```
django-admin startproject mysite
```

but it does not create directory of templates.

I create it manually but always when I run server to URL that are in templates directory. It always returns

> Django templates does not exist

Comment: You right click on the app directory and click *create directory*

Comment: i do that before but it returns error that django templates does not exist @WillemVanOnsem

Comment: that is because you need to add an extra directory with the app name in the `templates` directory, and in *that* directory you write the templates for that app.

Comment: do you have any image of this hierachy structural@WillemVanOnsem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

create `templates` directory in your project and complete the `TEMPLATES` setting in `settings.py` like this:

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```